# How can I solve "Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass" error in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm getting this error when I make a POST request to auth/login

```
[Nest] 8344   - 10/07/2020, 17:59:32   [ExceptionsHandler] Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass +811577ms
```

Error: Strategy#authenticate must be overridden by subclass
at LocalStrategy.Strategy.authenticate (/home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/passport-strategy/lib/strategy.js:21:9)
at attempt (/home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:366:16)
at authenticate (/home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:367:7)
at /home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:87:3
at new Promise ()
at /home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:79:83
at MixinAuthGuard. (/home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:48:36)
at Generator.next ()
at /home/damy/Projects/snippets/Typescript/simple-crud-with-nest/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:20:71
at new Promise ()

This is my local strategy code
[nestjs local strategy code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMdHH.png)

Answer (score 6):

You need to install and use `passport-local`. `passport` is an abstract implementation, and the `Strategy` from it is an `abstract` class meaning it can't be ran directly. If you use `passport-local` instead, the implementation is already there.

Comment: Great this worked for me!. If you are using `passport-jwt` you can also import `Strategy` from there

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza Import it from where?

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen Like this `import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';`

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem. I was importing from `'passport'`